# Network Connection in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Is there any way to detect the available network and connect directly in blackberry??
I have tried the following link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-Is-Network-API-alternative-for-legacy-OS/ta-p/614822 but getting the following error

```
 D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:8: package net.rim.device.api.io.http does not exist
    [javac] import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpHeaders;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:9: package net.rim.device.api.io.http does not exist
    [javac] import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpProtocolConstants;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:10: package net.rim.device.api.servicebook does not exist
    [javac] import net.rim.device.api.servicebook.ServiceBook;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:11: package net.rim.device.api.servicebook does not exist
    [javac] import net.rim.device.api.servicebook.ServiceRecord;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:12: package net.rim.device.api.system does not exist
    [javac] import net.rim.device.api.system.Branding;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:13: package net.rim.device.api.system does not exist
    [javac] import net.rim.device.api.system.CoverageInfo;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\sakina\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:14: package net.rim.device.api.system does not exist
    [javac] import net.rim.device.api.system.DeviceInfo;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:15: package net.rim.device.api.system does not exist
    [javac] import net.rim.device.api.system.WLANInfo;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:35: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServiceRecord
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] private static ServiceRecord srWAP2[];
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:80: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpHeaders
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] public HttpConnection getHttpConnection(String pURL, HttpHeaders headers) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\sakina\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:88: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpHeaders
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] public HttpConnection getHttpConnection(String pURL, HttpHeaders headers, byte[] data) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:123: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpHeaders
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] private HttpConnection tryHttpConnection(String pURL, int tIndex, HttpHeaders headers, byte[] data) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:61: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable DeviceInfo
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] sb.append(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName());
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:69: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Branding
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] sb.append(Branding.getVendorId());
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:206: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable HttpProtocolConstants
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] con.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, HttpProtocolConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED);
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:206: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable HttpProtocolConstants
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] con.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, HttpProtocolConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED);
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\bol
    [javac] symbol  : variable HttpProtocolConstants
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] con.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(data.length));
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:236: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable DeviceInfo
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:248: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable CoverageInfo
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(4 /* CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_BIS_B */)) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:255: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable CoverageInfo
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(2 /* CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS */)) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:262: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable WLANInfo
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\sakina\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:262: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable WLANInfo
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:271: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable CoverageInfo
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(1 /* CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT */) && (srWAP2 != null) && (srWAP2.length != 0)) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:278: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable CoverageInfo
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(1 /* CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT */)) {
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:305: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServiceBook
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\sTTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:305: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable ServiceBook
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:306: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServiceRecord
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] ServiceRecord[] records = sb.getRecords();
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:314: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServiceRecord
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] ServiceRecord myRecord = records[i];
    [javac] ^
    [javac] D:\TTMF_ProjectUAT1\TTMFBlackBerry\src\HttpConnectionFactory.java:326: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServiceRecord
    [javac] location: class HttpConnectionFactory
    [javac] srWAP2 = new ServiceRecord[wap2Vec.size()];
    [javac] ^
    [javac] 29 errors
    [javac] If an API-class was not found, you might need to define where to find the device-APIs. Following classpath has been used: [C:\Program Files\J2ME-Polish\import\mmapi.jar;C:\Program Files\J2ME-Polish\import\cldc-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\J2ME-Polish\import\midp-2.0.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/jsr238.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/jsr234.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/jsr211.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/jsr180.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/locationapi-1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/jsr177.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/jsr172.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/pdaapi.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/btapi.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/m3g.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/wmapi-2.0.jar;C:/Program Files/J2ME-Polish/import/m2g.jar].
```

BUILD FAILED

Despite of adding BlackBerry-5.0.0.jar file

Comment: I selected lines and pressed CTRL+K to make it to look a code.

Comment: The legacy API is intended for pre 5.0 devices. Yet it must compile, and i've used it without problems. If you are using 5.0+, use the Network API and TransportInfo stuff.

Comment: Is Blackberry 5.0.0.jar compatible with j2me polish???

Answer (score 0):

This is best way to getting available connection and run project smoothly

in following link i specified two classes

1)HttpConnectionFactory 
2)HttpConnectionFactoryException

[click here to see the above classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502915/tunnel-failed-exception-in-blackberry-curve-8520/8515091#8515091)

copy these two classes in to your project and

write following code (already specified into the link)
this will take care to checking all available connections in some order
1)WIFI
2)BIS
3)BES
4)TCP
5)WAP
which is first available then it will stop checking and take that connection to run project

```
HttpConnectionFactory factory = new HttpConnectionFactory(0);
        Httpconnection httpConnection = factory.getHttpConnection(url);
            if(httpConnection.getResponseCode()==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
//some of the connection in available
}else{
//no connection available
}
```

if i am wrong please ignore this

Comment: i have tried the above code but getting the following error 

"C:\Program Files\J2ME-Polish\j2mepolish-src\j2me\src\de\enough\polish\midp\ui\Form.java:42: interface expected here
    [javac] implements Displayable
    [javac] ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files\J2ME-Polish\j2mepolish-src\j2me\src\de\enough\polish\midp\ui\TextBox.java:42: interface expected here
    [javac] implements Displayable
    [javac] ^"


i guess blackberry-5.0.0 is not compatible with j2me-polish 2.1.4

Comment: what is this J2ME-Polish? r u working in blackberry or any other?

Comment: application is for blackberry with j2me polish for UI

Comment: in blackberry above code is perfectly working in 5.0 and above using RIM api

Comment: I have developed using eclipse 3.2.2 and Blackberry-5.0.0 jar,compiler compliance level 1.4,jdk 1.5 and j2mepolish-2.1.4.jar

Comment: once check this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Can-we-use-j2me-polish-in-the-Blackberry-development/td-p/28118 and let me know resolve or not

Answer (score 0):

If this [Link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/HttpConnectionFactory-Connection-class-problem-in-4-5/td-p/730035) and take the **HttpConnection.java** and try it. If it is not working then see the **"peter_strange"** post on that same link. There he provided links that will help you;