# BlackBerry HttpCOnnection

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection

/*    Hi Iam developing an application where the BB app needs to post data to server. The Http connection works fine on Blackberry emulator, but when i try to test it on a real device the application  cannot post data to server. the following is my code:
  */

```
package com.sims.datahandler;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

import com.sims.commonmethods.CommonMethods;
import com.sims.screens.MenuScreen;

/**
 * 
 * @author SaiKrishnaPawar
 *
 */
public class GPRSHandler extends Thread {

        private String data;
        private String url;
        private String msgKey;
        private String mobileNumber;

        public String sendGPRSRequest() {

             HttpConnection httpConn = null;
             DataOutputStream oStrm = null;
             DataInputStream is = null;

             byte[] resp = null;
             String responseData;
             try {

                 // Creating httpconnection object to handle GPRS request
                 httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);

                 httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
                 httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");
                 httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept_Language", "en-US");
                 httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                 oStrm = httpConn.openDataOutputStream();

                 byte dataArray[] = (mobileNumber + "&" + msgKey + data).getBytes();

//               byte dataArray[] = (msgKey + data).getBytes();

                 CommonMethods.getSystemOutput("msg key and data:::"+mobileNumber + msgKey + data);

                 for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                     oStrm.writeByte(dataArray[i]);
                 }
                 DataInputStream din = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
                 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 int ch;
                 while ((ch = din.read()) != -1) {
                     baos.write(ch);
                 }

                 resp = baos.toByteArray();
                 responseData = new String(resp);
                 baos.close();
                 din.close();
                 httpConn.close();

                 return responseData.trim();

             } catch (IOException ex) {

                 CommonMethods.getSystemOutput("IO Exception in run method of gprs handler::" + ex.getMessage());

                 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                    int choice = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK, "No Connectivity");

                    exitApp(choice);

                    }
                });

             } catch (NullPointerException nex) {

                 CommonMethods.getSystemOutput("NullPointerException:" + nex.getMessage());

             } catch (SecurityException e) {

                 CommonMethods.getSystemOutput("SecurityException:" + e.getMessage());

                 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        Dialog.ask(Dialog.OK, "Security Exception");

                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MenuScreen());

                    }
                });

             } finally {
                 try {
                     if (is != null) {
                         is.close();
                     }
                     if (oStrm != null) {
                         oStrm.close();
                     }
                     if (httpConn != null) {
                         httpConn.close();
                     }

                 } catch (Exception ex) {

                     UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            Dialog.ask(Dialog.OK, "ERROR in While Connecting GPRS Connection");

                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MenuScreen());

                        }
                    });
                 }
             }

             return null;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setMsgKey(String msgKey) {
            this.msgKey = msgKey;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url + ";deviceside=false";
        }

        public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {

            this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;

        }

        private void exitApp(int choice) {

            System.exit(0);

        }

}
```

Comment: How does it not post? Doesn't connect to your server? Bombs out? Returns bad data?

Comment: Please set your url in this code before open the connection...

Comment: You have to post some results you are getting from this code.. is the code throws any exception and are there any other issues?... From your code I think you are using MDS (;deviceside=false).. Also check your device connectivity.

Comment: @Marc it doesn't connect to the server on real device

Comment: @ BB expert: I am already setting the url at the bottom of code in setter method.

Comment: But you have to call that function..
Without calling any function how can you run the functionality of the function....

Comment: hi... the problem has been solved...depending on the network provider the apn settings need to be enabled..this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
```

instead of this you can write//

```
   url = url + ";deviceside=false";
   httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
```

Comment: At the end of the code , if u can see i am already appending url with deviceside=false

Comment: But you have to call that function..
Without calling any function how can you run the functionality of the function....

Comment: public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url + ";deviceside=false";
        }                   //where url is the local variable of class. iam passing the variable to this method and assigning it to a local variable.

Comment: in that function iam assigning the url value to another variable "url". that variable iam using to open the socket connection. The code is perfectly fine, my only issue is it is not working on real device.

Comment: Please add
                   setUrl(url);
This line before open the connection.
Once try it......

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6133/discussion-between-krisdroid-and-bb-expert)

Comment: hi... the problem has been solved...depending on the network provider the apn settings need to be enabled..this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Please add network extension in this line

```
 httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
```

at the end of the url please check did you add url extension 
for suppose you are using wifi then you have to add

```
   httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+";interface=wifi");
```

this is working for interface if you want to other types of networks then just refer my answer here

["Tunnel Failed" exception in BlackBerry Curve 8520](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502915/tunnel-failed-exception-in-blackberry-curve-8520/8515091#8515091)

Comment: ya but which is better static kay word extension or dynamic keyword extension dear? just i want to know please

Comment: if you have time please visit this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java for more discussions

Comment: At the end of the code , if u can see i am already appending url with deviceside=false

Comment: r u using wifi or any other ?

Comment: which connection are you using?

Comment: edge service provided by blackberry

Comment: please come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java i will explain you mmore