# RSS Reader for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, rss

I have been reading and trying the application given by IBM from this link [IBMRssReader](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-blackberry2/section3.html)

But I can't refresh the feed inside the simulator even though my MDS is turned on. Anyone having the same problems?

Or if any of you happened to find a reference of another RSS Reader code, it will be very helpful.

EDITED

From the Debug information I assume that the app managed to retrieve the feeds from the particular website, but can't display it to the screen. I am still wondering why. Is there any other way to parse XML feed instead of SAX parser?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is common issue just open your IBMRssComms.java class

and change this singe line

```
httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(theFeed.getUrl());
```

to

```
   httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(theFeed.getUrl()+";interface=wifi");
```

means this is connection extension issue. why the author didi not add this i dont know bot as per my knowledge you need to connection extension.

> note: ;inteface=wifi is only work for when devise using wifi. If you want to make globalized then please check following link for connection extensions

[Connection Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515091/914111)

Comment: Hi @HelpMeToHelpYou , but the app still cannot run using your suggestion. I am wondering why? Been google-ing for solutions yet I can't find a working one.

Comment: no dear i already check it is successfully completed. are you testing in emulator or device?