# bad request 400 when connect BIS on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, connection

I have a problem when I'm connecting BIS, I get an answer from server 400. That is a bad request. But when I'm connecting wifi, I don't have this problem. This problem appear when I have redirect in the web page and there are some files  CSS didn't appear correctly.
I use this suffix `;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public` when i'm connecting BIS.

Any one have an idea about that?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8515091/914111 you are using right extension.One more time check is it taking exactly or not...

Comment: No i have the application installed on my mobile